# Command pattern: How to handle multiple interaction tools?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, command-pattern

Hi I am curious about how I best would create a generalized structure to handle multiple interaction tools in a command pattern setting. (Think polygon creation line drawing or similar)

Here are some ideas I get on the top of my head.

1. Should I send a command for each interaction?
2. Should I create a builder to handle all interaction until the command is aborted or finished and then send a single command?
3. Should I create a composite command class that sends a start command then intermidiates and then a stop command to my receiver?

What is common practice?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. This question is off topic as you really should have known with 2.5K rep ;)  _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: I will change the question. What I need is actually a specific answer to this programming related question.

Comment: I consider this a a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. What I wanted was some reference to literature with the answer.

Comment: Something which is specifically off topic at SO. Sorry. I did not write the rules. Post effort and code or ask at code review

Comment: Under what not to ask in the help center I find that subjective questions are allowed and that if asking such questions They should: insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.

Comment: Point 4: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - as I posted in my first comment: _What I wanted was some reference to literature with the answer._

Comment: Great I consider it resolved then.